# ImportError: libportaudio.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in raspberry-pi4

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pyaudio, raspberry-pi4, pyaudioanalysis

**My code:**

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("talk")
    audio_text = r.listen(source)
    print("time over")
    
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio_text)
        print("converting the audio text into transript")
        print(text)
    except:
       print("Run again")
```

> almost I checked the all posiblity

**Error OCCURED**

```
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: libportaudio.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/sample.py", line 6, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

Answer (score 12):

For Python3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio
```

works like a charm
if it doesn't try other ideas [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=25173)